# template template arguments with a constant

Tags: c++, templates

My class looks like this, so far.

```
template< template<int dim, class T> class search_space> class  abstract_search_algorithm {

private:
    class search_space<dim, class T> & ssp; //error: dim not declared in scope

//public:
//  abstract_search_algorithm(search_space<int dim, T>& ss) : ssp(ss) { }

//  virtual std::array<T, dim> execute() = 0;
//  virtual ~abstract_search_algorithm() { }

};
```

As you see,  the argument to a `search_algorithm` will be templated  class. Now, I  would to store  a reference to that class in the agorithm class, but what  is  the correct type of it?

Comment: Those arguments have to come from *somewhere* before the template template can be used and thus fleshed out. Currently you're simply not providing them. Declaring the template template just means you're going to provide a template that takes a `int` and arbitrary class `T` as template arguments. Great, but the template template doesn't do much without those (nothing in fact).

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
template <typename T> class abstract_search_algorithm;
```

And specialization:

```
template<template<int, class> class search_space, int dim, typename T>
class abstract_search_algorithm<search_space<dim, T>> {
    // Your implementation.
};
```